# How to export from ArcMap to tab-delimited text file, while preserving formatting and values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, export, excel

I'm working with a complicated fGDB featureclass which contains hundreds of fields, in a variety of text and numerical formats. This is proving difficult to export into tab-delimited text file format.

**The problem**

After opening the table in ArcMap:

- Export to DBF results in the numbers being handled correctly, but the field names being truncated after 8 characters
- Export to Text results in the numbers being placed in quotations with commas separating the thousands (eg *"5,181,613"*) and commas (not tabs) separating the values. This makes it difficult to replace the commas with tabs

**My current workaround**

- export the table to DBF in ArcMap
- export it again to CSV
- edit the CSV file and remove the values, retaining just the headers
- replace the commas in the headers with tabs
- open the DBF file in Excel
- export from Excel to a new tab-delimited text file (which has truncated headers)
- copy/paste the headers from the edited headers file

Please tell me there's an easier way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly export to Excel file using the Table To Excel (Conversion) tool. No field name truncation and no formatting issue with numbers:

[Table To Excel (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000)

Then you can easily export to a correct csv(txt) file from excel

Comment: Wait, are you telling me that Esri have once again written some really useful functionality, and not exposed it to the ArcMap UI? Instead I need to open ArcToolbox like an animal? (Thanks for the tip!)

Comment: You are welcome. Actually This tool is there since version 10 of ArcGIS ;)

Comment: It would be kind of nice if they'd expose it to the > Export window in ArcMap's table - like, you know, all the other data formats....

Comment: `ERROR 001530: Input table exceeds the 256 columns limit of the .xls file format` - lucky I have a workaround, and lots of patience